Subdivision Surface creating weird things
I have another problem :)
So I'm still making this building, and I'm trying to smooth it with subdivision surface and edge split, but it always creates extra "faces".
I'm using a cylinder for the building and another cylinder to create a hole in the middle.

I have already tried so many things and none work. If i press J in edit mode with vertex select (1), it appears "Report:error invalid selection order".
Please explain like I'm a child because I don't really know much about blender.
I'm trying to make a 3d project of a museum like this:


hello could you please show an image of the shape you are trying to achieve? Boolean is not always the best way to do it, it's a last resort solution

@moonboots https://pt.pinterest.com/pin/677651075215833155/
I'm trying to make a 3d project of a museum like this. I searched for a tutorial (since I'm a zero in blender) and this seems like the "easiest" and best option. If u have another that will, somehow, benefit me, I appreciate.

Have you tried with a circle and some extrusions?

If you look closely, that circular building seems to be composed of a repeating modular structure with similar parts, polar arrayed around a center. It would probably be much easier to make the shape for one of those modules independently, and then duplicate it around a center. Avoid booleans, especially this early in the process, even more so if you plan to use Subdivision Surface. Either way, Subdivision Surface is also something you generally avoid for architecture.

That sounds really difficult, do you know any other app/site to make this?
@moonboots I don't even know what is an extrusion. English is not my first language, I'm sorry, but no, I didn't try it yet.

so maybe follow some tutorials on basic modeling in Blender?

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.
